# nodejs Request ignoring proxy settings for HTTPS

Tags: node.js, proxy

node Request module ignore proxy and expose server IP while requesting any HTTPS addresses. Everything work fine when requesting HTTP addresses. What's wrong?

```
    const request = require('request'),
    zlib = require('zlib'),
    fs = require('fs')
var cb = 1
request.get({
    timeout: 45000,
    gzip: true,
    pool: false,
    followRedirect: false,
    headers: {},
    url: 'https://api.ipify.org?format=json',
    proxy: '111.64.234.5:31218'
}).on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err + 'ERRRRRRRORRRRRR')
}).on('response', function (res) {
    var chunks = [];
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
    });
    res.on('end', function () {
        var buffer = Buffer.concat(chunks);
        var encoding = res.headers['content-encoding'];
        if (cb) {
            cb = 0
            if (encoding == 'gzip') {
                zlib.gunzip(buffer, function (err, decoded) {
                    console.log(decoded.toString())
                });
            } else if (encoding == 'deflate') {
                zlib.inflateRaw(buffer, function (err, decoded) { //inflate instead ???
                    console.log(decoded.toString())
                })
            } else {
                console.log(buffer.toString())
            }
        }
    });
})
```

You can try any IP:PORT as proxy. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try temporarily setting `pool` to true? I noticed myself I am facing proxy issues with pool disabled and I found your issue while researching this problem.